Jetpack Compose animateContentSize with shadow flickering
I'm trying to create a custom bottom sheet that has a shadow and animations for when it opens, or when it size changes (content dependent). I'm using animateContentSize() to handle the size changes, but get this weird issue with dark flickering at the bottom of the tray:

This is my current code, that causes the flickering:
AnimatedVisibility(
    visible = isVisible,
    enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
    exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it }),
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Transparent),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomCenter,

        ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .let {
                    if (bottomBar.isFixedSize) it.height(bottomTrayMaxHeight) else it.heightIn(
                        max = bottomTrayMaxHeight
                    )
                }
                .shadow(
                    elevation = 16.dp,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 8.dp, topEnd = 8.dp),
                )  // for top shadow
                .animateContentSize(),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background,
        ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

What I have tried in a "sandbox", and worked, is this:
@Composable
fun CustomBottomTray(isVisible: Boolean, trayHeight: Dp) {
    val transition = updateTransition(targetState = trayHeight, label = "TrayHeightTransition")
    val animatedHeight by transition.animateDp(
        label = "AnimateHeight",
        transitionSpec = { tween(durationMillis = 200, easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing) },
    ) { state ->
        state
    }

    val isAnimating = transition.isRunning

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = isVisible,
        enter = slideInVertically(
            initialOffsetY = { it },
        ),
        exit = slideOutVertically(
            targetOffsetY = { it },
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000),
        ),
    ) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .shadow(
                    elevation = if (!isAnimating) 8.dp else 0.dp,
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 8.dp, topEnd = 8.dp),
                )
                .height(animatedHeight),  // Apply height directly with animation
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 16.dp, topEnd = 16.dp),
            colors = CardDefaults.elevatedCardColors(containerColor = Color.White),
        ) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

The issue is that in my real app, I do not know trayHeight in advance. I do know its max size as I calculate bottomTrayMaxHeight, but this doesn't help to know the actual size in advance.
I feel like it has something to do with the dynamic rendering of the shadow together with the animation, so I tried to dynamically apply the shadow when the animation has finished.
Any suggestions on how to solve this?
